# Create multi-level object from parameters as strings

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
{
  "root.apple.color": "red",
  "root.apple.shape": "circle",
  "root.peach[0].color": "green",
  "root.peach[1].color": "yellow",
}
```

How can I convert it to be an object like this:

```
{
  "root": {
    "apple": {
      "color": "red",
      "shape": "circle"
    },
    "peach": [
      {
        "color": "green" 
      },
      {
        "color": "yellow" 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically I need a function which will convert any array with values defined as top example to multi-level object with real parameters.

Comment: *"convert any array"* - Your sample input isn't an array. But anyway, where are you stuck? Perhaps start with a loop on Object.keys(input), and use split(".") on each key?

Comment: So, try to write one, and if you have a specific question related to your attempt to do it, post that question.

Comment: "I need" is not a question.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oXHaLPn24k5xS9RO9akB?p=info

Comment: @dfsq this works great but if I have more levels it fails - http://plnkr.co/edit/AjlmTmwT0CysU7sSN8Rh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extended solution using `Object.keys`, `String.split`, `Array.isArray`, `Array.forEach` functions:

```js
var obj = {
  "root.apple.color": "red",
  "root.apple.shape": "circle",
  "root.peach[0].color": "green",
  "root.peach[0].shape": "square",
  "root.peach[1].color": "yellow",
  "root.apple.info.items[0].type": "text",
  "root.apple.info.items[0].active": true,
  "root.apple.info.items[1].type": "image",
  "root.apple.info.items[1].active": false,
  "root.apple.exterior.toggle[0].id": "left",
  "root.apple.exterior.toggle[0].content": "Ext",
  "root.test": "testing"
},
    result = {};

function transformObject(obj, result) {
    var current,
        checkProp = function (prop, objItem, is_array, idx, val) {
            if (Array.isArray(current) && val) {
                if (typeof idx === 'number' && current[idx]){
                    current[idx][prop] = val;
                } else {
                    var o = {};
                    o[prop] = val;
                    current.push(o);
                }
                
            } else {
                objItem[prop] = objItem[prop] || ((!is_array) ? {} : []);
                if (val) objItem[prop] = val;
                current = objItem[prop];
            }  
        }, 
            re = /\[(\d)\]$/;

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
        var props = k.split("."),
            lastKey = props.length - 1,
            val = obj[k], idx;

        props.forEach(function (prop, k) {
            var is_array = re.test(prop);
            if (is_array) { idx = +prop.match(re)[1]; prop = prop.replace(re, ""); };
            
            checkProp(prop, (!current) ? result : current, is_array, idx, (k === lastKey) ? val : null);
        });
        current = null;
    });

    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(transformObject(obj, result), 0, 4));
```

Comment: It does not work very well if I have for example `{"root.peach[0].color": "green", "root.peach[0].shape": "circle"}`
It should output:
`{
  "root": {
    "peach": [
      {
        "color": "green",
        "shape": "circle",
      }
    ]
  }
}`

See this fiddle with more examples: https://jsfiddle.net/vn2pc9c4/2/

Comment: I have update your solution to fix arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/vn2pc9c4/4/

Comment: @Mato, I've also update my solution for more complex cases. See my update

Answer (score 0):

This implementation works just on object nesting. you can add array awareness to it by yourself.

```js
function nested(obj, strPropertyChain, value) {
  var props = strPropertyChain.split('.');
  var len = props.length;
  var o = obj[props[0]] = (obj[props[0]] || {});
  props.slice(1, len - 1)
    .forEach(prop => o = (o[prop] = {}));

  o[props[len - 1]] = value;
  return obj;
}

var obj1 = {
  "root.apple.color": "red",
  "root.apple.shape": "circle",
  "root.peach.color": "green",
  "root.pear.color": "yellow",
}

var obj2 = {}

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => nested(obj2, k, obj1[k]));

console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  may do like this;

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = isNaN(a[1]) ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};
var data = {
  "root.apple.color": "red",
  "root.apple.shape": "circle",
  "root.peach[0].color": "green",
  "root.peach[1].color": "yellow",
},
      ok = Object.keys(data),
       o = ok.reduce((o,k) => o.setNestedValue(...k.replace("[",".").replace("]","").split(".").concat(data[k])),{});
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

`Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` takes a series of arguments of which the last one is the value and the previous ones are, if string type the nested object properties or if integer, array indices. I had to turn your object keys into an array like `"root.peach[0].color": "green"` -> `["root, "peach", "0", "color", "green"]`. Then `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` will tell the "0" is in fact an array index.